# Test function in proof of boundary $H^2$-regularity (PDE Evans, Chapter 6.3)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am working on the theorem about boundary $H^2$-regularity of linear elliptic differential equations as presented in "Partial Differential Equations" by L.C. Evans. I have a problem understanding why the given test function is indeed a $H^1_0$-function.

Here is the theorem: Let $$Lu= - \sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}(x)u_{x_i})_{x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n b^{i}(x)u_{x_i} + c(x) u$$
be an elliptic linear operator of second order. We look at weak solutions of $Lu=f$ in a region $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ with boundary condition $u=0$ on $\partial U$. Now if $a^{ij} \in C^1(\bar U); b^i, c \in L^\infty(U)$ and $\partial U \in C^2$, any weak solution $u$ lies in $H^2(U)$ and we have an estimate for the $H^2$-norm of $u$.

For the proof we first look at $U = B(0,1) \cap \mathbb R^n_+$, so $\partial U$ consists of $\{x_n=0\}$ and of a curved part of the ball.
In the proof, Evans intends to use a special $H^1_0$-function in the definition of a weak solution, namely $$v= - D_k^{-h}(\zeta^2 D_k^hu)$$
where $\zeta$ is a cutoff function that vanishes on $\mathbb R^n \backslash B(0,1)$ and $k \ne n$.
He claims this is a $H^1_0(U)$-function but I don't understand the reasoning there.
He calculates that
$$v(x) = \frac{1}{h^2} \bigg [ \zeta^2(x-he_k) (u(x)-u(x-he_k) - \zeta^2(x)(u(x+he_k)-u(x)) \bigg ]$$

He then claims that $v=0$ on $x_n=0$ because this is the case for $u$ (as $u$ is a weak solution for $Lu=f$ and $u=0$ on $\partial U$) and because $k \ne n$. I understand the reasoning here: every term with a $u$ in the formula for $v$ is $\equiv 0$, because $u(x)=u(x \pm he_k)=0$ if $x_n=0$ due to $k \ne n$.
For the curved part, Evans says that $v$ vanishes there because $\zeta$ does. And that is where my problem lies. I get that the $\zeta^2(x)$-term vanishes when $x$ lies on the curved part. But what about $\zeta^2(x-he_k)$?

If $x$ lies on the curved part of the boundary, $x-he_k$ does NOT need to lie on the curved part. However, I guess there is some kind of continuity argument or something else I am overlooking at the moment. I would appreciate if someone would help me understand how we can get to $v \in H^1_0(U)$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is $h$ supposed to be small? If that is the case and $x$ is not in the support of $\zeta$, then $x\pm he_k$ won't be in it either.

Comment: Oh, I see - if $\zeta \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb R^n \backslash B(0,1)$, it is also zero on $S^n=\{||x||=1\}$ (the boundary of $B(0,1)$). But couldn't $\zeta$ be $\ne 0$ everywhere on $B(0,1)$, so also at any point $x \pm he_k$, even for small $h$?

Comment: Or is the following argument correct: The support of $\zeta$ is by definition closed, so $\mathbb R^n \backslash \text{spt}(\zeta)$ is open. If $x$ is not in spt$(\zeta)$ so is any point in a small ball around $x$. Is that the reason for $\zeta$ also vanishing at $x \pm he_k$ when $h$ is sufficiently small?

Comment: The second argument sounds convincing to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!